# Why the new user cannot login after registration using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I can only login with the credentials defined in the `.inMemoryAuthentication()`. When somebody makes a registration the user details (email, password) successfully will be saved in the PostgreSQL database but when the user wants to login with the given details it says "Wrong username and password". What am I missing?

**SecurityConf.java**

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    String[] staticResources  =  {
            "/css/**",
            "/images/**"

        };

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return super.userDetailsService();  
    }


    private UserDetailsService userService;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserDetailsService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    @Autowired
    public void configureAuth(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {

        try {
            auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user")
                .password("{noop}user") //Add password storage format, for plain text, add {noop} avoiding the error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
                .roles("ADMIN")
            .and()
                .withUser("admin")
                .password("{noop}admin")
                .roles("ADMIN");
        } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println(" " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(staticResources);


    }
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSec) {


        try {
            httpSec.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(staticResources).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/reg").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .permitAll();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(" " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**ApiController.java**

```
public class ApiController {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private EmailService emailService;
    private UserService userService;


    @Autowired
    public void setEmailService(EmailService emailService) {
        this.emailService = emailService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/registration")
    public String registration(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "registration";
    }
    //@RequestMapping(value="/reg", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @PostMapping("/reg")
    public String registration(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        System.out.println("NEW USER");
        emailService.sendMessage(user.getEmail(), user.getFullName());
        log.info("New User");
//      log.debug(user.getPassword());
//      log.debug(user.getEmail());
        userService.registerUser(user);
        return "auth/login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/activation/{code}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String activation(@PathVariable("code") String code, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String result = userService.userActivation(code);
        return "auth/login?activationsuccess";
    }

}
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String password;

    private String fullName;

    boolean enabled;
    String activation;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable( 
        name = "users_roles", 
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id")}, 
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id")}  
    )
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

    public User() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public String getActivation() {
        return activation;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public void setActivation(String activation) {
        this.activation = activation;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", email=" + email + ", password=" + password + ", fullName=" + fullName + "]";
    }

    public void addRoles(String roleName) {
        if (this.roles == null || this.roles.isEmpty()) {
            this.roles = new HashSet<>();
            this.roles.add(new Role(roleName));
        }
    }
    }
```

**Role.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String role;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

    private Role() {

    }

    public Role(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Role [id=" + id + ", role=" + role + ", users=" + users + "]";
    }

}
```

**RoleRepository**

```
public interface RoleRepository extends CrudRepository<Role, Long> {

    Role findByRole(String role);

}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByEmail(String email);

    User findByActivation(String code);
}
```

**UserDetailsImpl.java**

```
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5461896565515368402L;

    private User user;

    public UserDetailsImpl(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        Set<Role> roles = user.getRoles();
        for(Role role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
        }
        return authorities;
    }
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return user.getEnabled();
    }

}
```

**UserService.java**

```
public interface UserService {

    public String registerUser(User user);

    public User findByEmail(String email);

    public String userActivation(String code);

}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, UserDetailsService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    private final String USER_ROLE = "USER";

    @Autowired
    public void UserRepository(UserRepository userRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }
    @Override
    public User findByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = findByEmail(username);
        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        return new UserDetailsImpl(user);
    }
    @Override
    public String registerUser(User userToRegister) {
        User userCheck = userRepository.findByEmail(userToRegister.getEmail());
        if (userCheck != null) {
            return "alreadyExist";
        }

        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByRole(USER_ROLE);
        if (userRole != null) {
            userToRegister.getRoles().add(userRole);
        } else {
            userToRegister.addRoles(USER_ROLE);
        }
        userToRegister.setActivation(generateKey());
        userToRegister.setEnabled(true);
        userRepository.save(userToRegister);

        return "ok";
    }
    public String generateKey() {
        String key = "";
        Random random = new Random();
        char[] word = new char[16];
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            word[i] = (char) ('a' + random.nextInt(26));
        }
        String toReturn = new String(word);

        return new String(word);
    }
    @Override
    public String userActivation(String code) {

        User user = userRepository.findByActivation(code);
        if (user == null) {
            return "no result";
        }

        user.setEnabled(true);
        user.setActivation("");
        userRepository.save(user);

        return "ok";

    }
}
```

**login.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--We are choosing these two to let the browser to load faster-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/logincss.css">
    <!--this is the last one so that we can override previous boostrap styles if we want-->

    <head>

    <body class="signin-body">
        <div class="container signin-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
                    <div class="card signin-card">
                        <div class="card-block">
                          <!-- <img src="/imgages/logindetails.png" class="img-fluid signin-img"> -->
                          <img src="images/logindetails.png" width="50%" height="50%" class="img-fluid signin-img">
                            <form name="login" th:action="@{/login}" method="post" class="signin-form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
                                    <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-danger">Wrong username and password</div>
                                    <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">You successfully logged out</div>
                                    <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="true">
                                    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="true">
                                </div>  
                                    </div>                               
                                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block signin-btn" type="submit">Login</button>
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
                              <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Remember me <a href="#"> Need help?</a></label>
                            </div>
                        </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class= "new-account" href="/registration">Create New Account</a>
            </div>
        <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
</div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="css/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: In your `registerUser` method you are not setting a password value for the User that you are saving to your database. I believe that this will leave the password field as `null` - can you verify this in the database?

Comment: Hey @NimbleNavigator. Every data is visible in the database, the password too.

Comment: Can you put `Role` class and `RoleRepository` interface too?

Comment: Hello @Nasir, added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below snippet code to your security config class

```
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
```

Add below code to your `UserServiceImpl` class

```
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
```

Encrypt user password before saving in the database.

```
    userToRegister.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userToRegister.getPassword()));
```